# How to fix Carthage Build Error: "SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported" when Swift 5 is selected

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage, swift5

I am migrating a "NetworkFoundation" Framework, which is based on Alamofire, to Swift 5. Carthage is being used as the dependency manager,

The cartfile looks the following:

> github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "5.0.0-beta.5"

The command `carthage update` is executed with success. In Xcode the project builds, but when I run the command `carthage build --no-skip-current` in the root directory of my framework it fails:

> xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/1m/qjb4gks13d54rqmn9ptwjmmw0000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.bg5VCR.log
>
> Building scheme "Alamofire macOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> Building scheme "Alamofire tvOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> Building scheme "Alamofire watchOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> Building scheme "MyNetworkFoundation" in MyNetworkFoundation.xcodeproj
>
> Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
>
> Build Failed
>
> > Task failed with exit code 65:
> >
> > > /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/MyUser/Documents/Projects/MyNetworkFoundation/MyNetworkFoundation/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme Alamofire\ iOS -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/1m/qjb4gks13d54rqmn9ptwjmmw0000gp/T/MyNetworkFoundation SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/MyUser/Documents/Projects/MyNetworkFoundation)
>
> This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/1m/qjb4gks13d54rqmn9ptwjmmw0000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.bg5VCR.log

As recommended, I checked the logfile of the failed build. In there it says:

`error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'Alamofire iOS') ** ARCHIVE FAILED **`

So I checked the Swift Version of my Project which seems to be correct.
[image: MyNetworkFoundation Build Settings]

Because the logfile states that the Swift Version 3.0 is used in target 'Alamofire iOS', I checked the targets in

> /MyNetworkFoundation/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Alamofire.xcodeproj

but all of them have Swift Version 5.
I have no idea what why that error is appearing when I want to build my project. I even tried re-installing Xcode but that did not work either. Anybody got an idea what I am missing?

Xcode Version: 10.2.1 (10E1001)
MacOS Version: 10.14.5 (18F132)

Comment: what is your pod code to install Alamofire?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the issue for you but I was experiencing something similar. For me, since I just copied the repo of a project I was onboarding to, I was running `carthage bootstrap` and it always failed for Alamofire with Swift 3 errors like yours.

My Cartfile file has `github "Alamofire/Alamofire"  ~> 4.7.2`, and my project is using Swift 4.2 (so again, not exactly the same as your setup).

I finally got it to work running the following command:

`carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries --toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_4_2`

I believe the trick was to specify the toolchain use Swift 4.2, so I would suggest you try with Swift_5_0. Hope this helps!